# SSRS - Limiting results using multiple parameters

Tags: reporting-services

I'm creating a debtor invoicing report which has two parameters.

Parameter 1: This is a single value parameter called `@booking_date`. I filter the results(main dataset) by adding this into the query as a query parameter.

> Eg. `WHERE BookingDate = @booking_Date`

Parameter 2: This parameter has two specified values - Yes or No. The parameter is called `@live_run` and the default value is 'No'. Basically, when this parameter has the default value of 'No', it  does not limit/effect the results in any way. On the other hand, when this parameter has a value of 'Yes', it should limit the results by only displaying the bookings where the invoice has been paid off. There is a field I can use for this called `Booking_Paid_off` as follows - `WHERE Booking_Paid_Off = 1.`

I have parameter 1 in place, but I am unsure how to bring in Parameter 2 because it will be based on two conditions, do I need to use an If statement or a case statement? Do I need to create a new dataset for the second Parameter? I only want to limit the results with Parameter 2 ONLY if Parameter 2 has a value of Yes, otherwise I want the results to stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options. You can switch out the Dataset entirely based on the parameter or use an IF inside the dataset to determine which query to run or simply check the parameter in your WHERE clause.

I recommend the latter.

```
SELECT 
    Field1, 
    Field2 
FROM 
    Table1 
WHERE
    (
        (@live_run = 'Yes' and Booking_Paid_Off = 1)
        or (@live_run <> 'Yes')
    )
```